# Showing up highchart after submitting form in other file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Kindly need help...
I want to show Highchart in file_1, when highchart script is on file_2..
i'm using PHP, Jquery and AJAX...
here is the script

SCR_test02.php

```
<?php 

require "function.inc.php";
//require "showscr.php";

include "conn.php";
include "q_table.php";

?> 

<form name="scr_form">
<table border="1" align="center" width="80%">
<tr>
  <td align="center">
   <input type="button" onClick="SCRajaxFunction()" value="Submit" id="sub">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="reset">
  </td> 
 </tr>  
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">&nbsp;
    <div id="scr"></div>
    </td>

</tr>


</table>

</form>
<script src="../Highcharts-3.0.5/js/highcharts.js"></script>


</html>
```

function.inc

```
var htmlobjek; 
$(document).ready(function()
{ 

  $("#region").change(function()
  {
    var region = $("#region").val(); 
    $.ajax(
    { 
        url: "GetMSC.php", 
        data: "region="+region, 
        cache: false, 
        success: function(msg)
        {   
            $("#msc").val(msg); 
        } 
    }); 
  }); 
}); 



//Ketika form di submit
function SCRajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('scr');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var period = document.getElementById('period').value;
    var datefrom = document.getElementById('datefrom').value;
    var dateto = document.getElementById('dateto').value;
    var region = document.getElementById('region').value;
    var msc = document.getElementById('msc').value;
    //var rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
    var dataString = "?datefrom=" + datefrom + "&dateto=" + dateto + "&region=" + region + "&msc=" + msc + "&period=" + period;// + "&rows=" + rows;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ShowSCR.php" + dataString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

ShowSCR

```
<html>  

<?
require "function.inc.php";
    //require "highchart_tes.php";
    include "conn.php";

    $period = $_GET['period']; 
    $datefrom = $_GET['datefrom']; 
    $dateto = $_GET['dateto'];
    $region = $_GET['region'];
    $msc = $_GET['msc'];

        $drop=array(); 
        $drop2=array();     
        $traffic=array();
        $data1=array(); 
        $data2=array();
        $sql = "SELECT distinct Date_id, hour_id 
            FROM scrkpi_h
            WHERE Date_id >= '2012-12-01' 
            AND Date_id <= '2012-12-03'
            AND MSC like 'MSBDL%'
            ORDER BY Date_id ASC ";  
        $qry = mysql_query($sql,$koneksi) or die ("Gagal Query - ".mysql_error());  
        while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {  


            $a = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime($data['Date_id']));
            $data1[] = $a. $data[1];

        }  


?>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Highcharts-3.0.5/js/type/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Highcharts-3.0.5/js/highcharts.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


    var chart1;
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
            chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(
            {
                chart: {
                renderTo: 'scr_core'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'SCR Core ',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: 
                {
                    categories: ['<?php echo join($data1, "','") ?>'],
                    //['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

                    labels: 
                    {
                        rotation: -90
                    }   
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: '%'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y +' % (percentage)';
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: 
                [
                <?php //query tiap msc lbih dulu, baru tiap msc diambil datanya, dijadikan data berjajar berdasar koma
                $sql   = "SELECT distinct msc_id, MSC 
                        FROM `scrkpi_h` 
                        WHERE MSC like 'MSBDL%'"; //buat data di legend
                $query = mysql_query( $sql );
                while( $ret = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ){
                   $nId = $ret[0]; //query dari scrkpi_h, msc_id = array 0
                   $nodes = $ret[1];
                      $sql_   = "SELECT * FROM `scrkpi_h` 
                      WHERE `msc_id`='$nId' 
                      AND Date_id >= '2012-12-01' 
                      AND Date_id <= '2012-12-03'
                      AND MSC like 'MSBDL%'
                      ORDER BY Date_id ASC ";
                      $query_ = mysql_query( $sql_ );

                      $data = "";
                      while( $ret_ = mysql_fetch_array( $query_ ) ){
                         $kel = $ret_['scrCombine'];
                         $data = $data . "," . $kel;
                      }
                      $data = substr( $data , 1 , strlen( $data ) );
                ?>
                {
                    name: '<?php echo $nodes; ?>',
                    data: [<?php echo $data; ?>]
                      },
                <?php


                }
                ?>
                ]
            });
        });

</script>

<div id='scr_core' style='min-width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 0'></div>
</html>
```

The chart already show on file ShowSCR.php 
But i want to show it on  file SCR_test02.php at div="scr" when i click "submit" button
how to work it out, i have try many times but not working, really need help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because in you example SCR_test02.php you have lines

```
`require "function.inc.php";
//require "showscr.php";

include "conn.php";
include "q_table.php";`
```

but inside this files you have no chart initialization, only calling ajax and thats all. You need to add javascript highcharts calling or prepare extension in php, which will be common file for SCR_test02.php and ShowSCR, included by reguire declatarion.

EDIT:
common.php

```
<script src="path/to/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
  //highcharts initialization
</script>
```

Then in each files you use

```
require "common.php"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,, but i didnt know how to add javascript highcharts calling..
can u give an example?

Comment: still not working dude..
this is the flow of my example :
**SCR_test02.php** Sending data to **function.inc.php** which include open function to **ShowSCR.php** 
which in your example at least is the same..
if i give 
**require "common.php"(require "ShowSCR.php" in my version)** 
there will be an error because this script :
**$period = $_GET['period'];** 
**$datefrom = $_GET['datefrom'];** 
**$dateto = $_GET['dateto'];**
**$region = $_GET['region'];**
**$msc = $_GET['msc'];**
was not have any value yet